# Fatal error: Class 'setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTpl' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf\fpdi2\src\Fpdi.php

Tags: php, xampp, fpdi

i am currently using this code for the data.php but I get this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTpl' not found
```

and it says the problem originates in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf\fpdi2\src\Fpdi.php` on line 24.

I kept adding `the setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTpl` to that specific line and tried reloading it but no response and it results in the same error

`fpdi.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is part of FPDI
 *
 * @package   setasign\Fpdi
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2018 Setasign - Jan Slabon (https://www.setasign.com)
 * @license   http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license The MIT License
  */

namespace setasign\Fpdi;

use setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\CrossReference\CrossReferenceException;
use setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\PdfParserException;
use setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\Type\PdfIndirectObject;
use setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\Type\PdfNull;

/**
 * Class Fpdi
 *
 * This class let you import pages of existing PDF documents into a reusable structure for FPDF.
 *
 * @package setasign\Fpdi
 */
class Fpdi extends FpdfTpl
{ use \setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTpl;
    use FpdiTrait;

    /**
     * FPDI version
     *
     * @string
     */
    const VERSION = '2.1.1';

    /**
     * Draws an imported page or a template onto the page or another template.
     *
     * Omit one of the size parameters (width, height) to calculate the other one automatically in view to the aspect
     * ratio.
     *
     * @param mixed $tpl The template id
     * @param float|int|array $x The abscissa of upper-left corner. Alternatively you could use an assoc array
     *                           with the keys "x", "y", "width", "height", "adjustPageSize".
     * @param float|int $y The ordinate of upper-left corner.
     * @param float|int|null $width The width.
     * @param float|int|null $height The height.
     * @param bool $adjustPageSize
     * @return array The size
     * @see Fpdi::getTemplateSize()
     */
    public function useTemplate($tpl, $x = 0, $y = 0, $width = null, $height = null, $adjustPageSize = false)
    {
        if (isset($this->importedPages[$tpl])) {
            $size = $this->useImportedPage($tpl, $x, $y, $width, $height, $adjustPageSize);
            if ($this->currentTemplateId !== null) {
                $this->templates[$this->currentTemplateId]['resources']['templates']['importedPages'][$tpl] = $tpl;
            }
            return $size;
        }

        return parent::useTemplate($tpl, $x, $y, $width, $height, $adjustPageSize);
    }

    /**
     * Get the size of an imported page or template.
     *
     * Omit one of the size parameters (width, height) to calculate the other one automatically in view to the aspect
     * ratio.
     *
     * @param mixed $tpl The template id
     * @param float|int|null $width The width.
     * @param float|int|null $height The height.
     * @return array|bool An array with following keys: width, height, 0 (=width), 1 (=height), orientation (L or P)
     */
    public function getTemplateSize($tpl, $width = null, $height = null)
    {
        $size = parent::getTemplateSize($tpl, $width, $height);
        if ($size === false) {
            return $this->getImportedPageSize($tpl, $width, $height);
        }

        return $size;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @throws CrossReferenceException
     * @throws PdfParserException
     */
    protected function _putimages()
    {
        $this->currentReaderId = null;
        parent::_putimages();

        foreach ($this->importedPages as $key => $pageData) {
            $this->_newobj();
            $this->importedPages[$key]['objectNumber'] = $this->n;
            $this->currentReaderId = $pageData['readerId'];
            $this->writePdfType($pageData['stream']);
            $this->_put('endobj');
        }

        foreach (\array_keys($this->readers) as $readerId) {
            $parser = $this->getPdfReader($readerId)->getParser();
            $this->currentReaderId = $readerId;

            while (($objectNumber = \array_pop($this->objectsToCopy[$readerId])) !== null) {
                try {
                    $object = $parser->getIndirectObject($objectNumber);

                } catch (CrossReferenceException $e) {
                    if ($e->getCode() === CrossReferenceException::OBJECT_NOT_FOUND) {
                        $object = PdfIndirectObject::create($objectNumber, 0, new PdfNull());
                    } else {
                        throw $e;
                    }
                }

                $this->writePdfType($object);
            }
        }

        $this->currentReaderId = null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _putxobjectdict()
    {
        foreach ($this->importedPages as $key => $pageData) {
            $this->_put('/' . $pageData['id'] . ' ' . $pageData['objectNumber'] . ' 0 R');
        }

        parent::_putxobjectdict();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _put($s, $newLine = true)
    {
        if ($newLine) {
            $this->buffer .= $s . "\n";
        } else {
            $this->buffer .= $s;
        }
    }
}
```

`data.php`

```
     <?php  
    use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
    use \setasign\Fpdi\PdfReader;
    use \setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTpl;

    require_once('fpdf\fpdf.php');
    require_once('fpdi2\src\Fpdi.php');
    require_once('fpdi2\src\FpdfTpl.php');
    require_once('fpdi2\src\autoload.php');

    // Original file with multiple pages 
    $fullPathToFile = "Grade 11.pdf";

    class PDF extends FPDI {

        var $_tplIdx;

        function Header() {

            global $fullPathToFile;

            if (is_null($this->_tplIdx)) {

                // THIS IS WHERE YOU GET THE NUMBER OF PAGES
                $this->numPages = $this->setSourceFile($fullPathToFile);
                $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);

            }
            $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx, 0, 0,200);

        }

        function Footer() {}

    }

    // initiate PDF
    $pdf = new PDF();

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();


    // The new content
    $pdf->SetFont("helvetica", "B", 25);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
    $pdf->Text(40,120,"Sample Text over overlay");

    // THIS PUTS THE REMAINDER OF THE PAGES IN
    if($pdf->numPages>1) {
        for($i=2;$i<=$pdf->numPages;$i++) {
            //$pdf->endPage();
            $pdf->_tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);
            $pdf->AddPage();
        }
    }

    //show the PDF in page
    //$pdf->Output();

    // or Output the file as forced download
    $pdf->Output("sampleUpdated.pdf", 'D');
```

If someone could help me out on this, it would be a lifesaver for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just require only the autoload.php and no class manually:

```
require_once('fpdf\fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi2\src\autoload.php');
```